# Access nested content generated on the fly via CSS and Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I am trying to access the anchor link within a table and within a div.  I have not had any luck accessing the CSS properties so that I can capture a click event with jQuery. The content of this inline dialog is generated on the fly.

```
<div id="cds-cad-inline-dialog" style="">
    <div>The model you requested has been successfully generated.</div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <a href="alinktoadownloadfile">Download File</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

I have tried the following:

```
            $("div.a#cds-cad-container").click(function () {
                $("#cds-cad-static-3D-viewer").show();
                $("#cds-cad-inline-dialog").hide();
            });
```

and

```
            $("div.table.tbody.tr.td.div.a").click(function () {
                $("#cds-cad-static-3D-viewer").show();
                $("#cds-cad-inline-dialog").hide();
            });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

### CODE BEFORE

```
    <form id="_3d" runat="server">
        <div id="show_3d" runat="server" style="display:block;width:635px">
            <div id="cds-cad-container">
                <div id="cds-cad-inline-dialog" style="display:none;"></div>
```

### CODE AFTER

See above.

Comment: Where is the element with id = "cds-cad-container" in the HTML? I don't see it.

Comment: what is exactly your html at start and your html after the live insert ?

Comment: Updated to show html at the start.  The code at the top is the 'after' code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#cds-cad-container").on("click","table div a",function(event){
    alert("hello world, href : "+$(this).attr("href"));
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: The download link is still working but the click or on event is not firing which hides and shows..

Comment: try with the edit, .on work as .live for specified selector only (second parameter with the "a")

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors are incorrect.  Try

```
$("#cds-cad-container a").click(function () {
```

Your previous "div.a#cds-cad-container" is trying to select a `div` with class `a`.

and

```
$("div table tbody tr td div a").click(function () {
```

You were using dots in this one, which is a class selector.  Use spaces to select nested elements that may have intervening elements.

Comment: Maybe OP could fix the 1st one just changing the <dot> "." to a space too. I like your selector better though.

Comment: I'm sorry to report that the above did not work.  Could it have something to do with the link being a download link or that it is generated on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

Just like to add that if you use 
`$("#cds-cad-container a").click(function () {
//your code
});` then make sure you have only a single anchor tag that you want to add the click event to.

This will attach click event to all the available anchor tags under the div with the id `cds-cad-container`.

To avoid it you can write something like this :

`var test = $("#cds-cad-container a")[0].onclick = function(){console.log("test")};`

This will attach the click event only to the 1st anchor tag under the div with the id `cds-cad-container`.

Hope this helps.